# How to use Jetpack compose app bar backbutton

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-jetpack-compose

getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true) this i was using for normal android AppCompatActivity to switch between two or more activity.can any one tell me how to do this in jetpack Compose ?

Comment: Are you using Navigation for Compose or something else for navigating between screens in Compose UI?

Comment: If you are using material TopAppBar then you can ```navigationIcon = {
                    IconButton(onClick = { }) {
                        Icon(Icons.Filled.ArrowBack, "")
                    }```
                },

Comment: i want to use without navigation bar

Answer (score 34):

The other answer is correct for showing the back button. This is a slight alternative that uses `TopAppBar` composable instead.

I also ran into a similar issue.  The main thing I wanted to solve was hiding the back button when you are at the root or if there is nothing left in backstack, since `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled` took care of that as long as you specified your parent.
Assuming you are using the nav controller with compose, you can do something like this

```
val navController = rememberNavController()
Scaffold(
    topBar = {
        TopAppBar(
            title = { Text(text = "app bar title") },
            navigationIcon = if (navController.previousBackStackEntry != null) {
                {
                    IconButton(onClick = { navController.navigateUp() }) {
                        Icon(
                            imageVector = Icons.Filled.ArrowBack,
                            contentDescription = "Back"
                        )
                    }
                }
            } else {
                null
            }

        )
    },
    content = {
        // Body content
    }
)
```

The key here is to set `navigationIcon` argument of `TopAppBar` to `null` when there is nothing in the back stack.  This way the back arrow will be hidden when you are at the root and shown otherwise.

Comment: Provided suggestion only works if there is a scaffold recomposition

Comment: As pointed out by @user2003047, the arrow was still visible on the parent screens. I used route name information from `NavDestination` to fix it.

```
if(navBackStackEntry?.destination?.route == AppScreens.PARENT_SCREEN.name)
```

Comment: As pointed by my previuos comment the provided suggestion only works if there is a scaffold recomposition. To recompose on navigation event you can use the following state `val currentBackStackEntry by navController.currentBackStackEntryAsState()`
I have a full sample available on github: https://github.com/pgatti86/toolbar-demo

Comment: @paolo Google has made things so complicated that it took me an hour to implement a toolbar with back navigation. Anyway your method using state worked. Thanks ton!

Answer (score 4):

Here a full Example of using compose app bar back button. https://github.com/pgatti86/toolbar-demo

```
val navController: NavHostController = rememberNavController()
   
 val isBackButtonVisible by remember {
  derivedStateOf { 
    navController.previousBackStackEntry != null 
  } 
}
```

use derived state to show or hide your back button icon

Answer (score 3):

You can wrap your main content inside an `Scaffold` composable and use the `topBar` to add the back button and handle back action like this:

```
 import androidx.compose.material.Scaffold
 .
 .

 Scaffold(
      topBar = {
           Row {
               Icon(
               imageVector = Icons.Filled.ArrowBack,
               contentDescription = "Back",
               modifier = Modifier
                         .padding(16.dp)
                         .clickable {
                            // Implement back action here
                          }
                   )
              }
          }
    ) {
       BodyContent()
    }
```

Comment: For normal activity we don't have to write the code manually to get the previous activity or parent activity.how to do this here? what to write in the click event because if i create new intent it ill be create one more instance of the activity

Comment: Check the answer from here, when you get the current activity you can finish is to move to the previous one.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69234880/how-to-get-intent-data-in-a-composable

Answer (score 3):

Both other solutions are fine and helped me refine my own variation that I have to extract because of usage on many screens.

```
@Composable
fun MyScaffold(@StringRes titleId: Int, upAvailable: Boolean, onUpClicked: () -> Unit, content: @Composable (PaddingValues) -> Unit) {
    Scaffold(
        topBar = {
            TopAppBar(title = { MyText(textId = titleId) }, backgroundColor = Color.Black, navigationIcon = {
                if (upAvailable) {
                    IconButton(onClick = { onUpClicked() }) {
                        Icon(imageVector = Icons.Filled.ArrowBack, contentDescription = "Back", tint = Color.White)
                    }
                }
            })
        },
        backgroundColor = Color.Transparent,
        content = content
    )
}
```

Where MyText is just my variant that accepts string res and has white text color.

Usage:

```
val isUpAvailable by viewModel.upAvailable.collectAsState()

MyScaffold(titleId = R.string.title, upAvailable = isUpAvailable, onUpClicked = { viewModel.navigateUp() }) {
 // Content
}
```

Then my BaseViewModel provides upAvailable and navigateUp() via navigationManager dependency which handles navigation via navigationController:

```
if (destination.route == NAVIGATE_UP) { navController.navigateUp() }


...

// set on every navigation
navigationManager.setUpAvailable(navController.previousBackStackEntry != null)
```

Comment: Could you add your ViewModel code?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way by my opinion is with **BackHandler Composable**. I use it in my little apps where everything composes in one Activity. You don't even need NavHost. For Example:

```
@Composable
fun Screen2 (
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    goHomeScreen: () -> Unit
)
{

    val noteViewModel: NoteViewModel = viewModel()
    NoteOpen (noteViewModel = noteViewModel, modifier = modifier, goHomeScreen = goHomeScreen)
    BackHandler (
        onBack = { goHomeScreen() },
        enabled = true
            )
}
```

---

//In MainActivity.kt for example:

```
@Composable
fun MemoMain(
    ...,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    memoViewModel: MemoViewModel = viewModel()
) {
 var activeNoteIndex by rememberSaveable { mutableIntStateOf(-1) }

    if (activeNoteIndex == 0) {
        Screen2(
            modifier = modifier,
            dbDao = memoViewModel.noteDao,
            goHomeScreen =  { activeNoteIndex = -1 },
            activeNote = activeNote
        )
    } else {
        MemoApp(
            modifier = modifier,
            memoViewModel = memoViewModel,
            noteList = homeUiState.noteList,
            goScreen2 = { activeNoteIndex = it }
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: How do we implement `goHomeScreen`?

Comment: I've edited the antwort to show one example of using self-made navigation. Var activeNoteIndex is used for navigation between screens and for app logic too.