# How to get Intent Data in a Composable

Tags: android-intent, android-jetpack-compose

When I am starting an `Activity`, I am passing some data to. it via the `Intent`. How can I access this data from Intent inside a composable?

I am looking for a way to directly access the `Intent` from a composable.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can get current activity from the `LocalContext`. And this using activity you can get intent:

```kotlin
val context = LocalContext.current
val activity = context.findActivity()
val intent = activity?.intent
```

`findActivity`:

```kotlin
fun Context.findActivity(): Activity? = when (this) {
    is Activity -> this
    is ContextWrapper -> baseContext.findActivity()
    else -> null
}
```