# How can I pass data from Bottomsheet to the activity in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I have researched this topic for a while and it has been without answers. I want to pass data from Bottomsheet to the activity in Jetpack compose. For example, I want to be able to change the type of fonts used, just like Amazon Kindle does. I have everything in place on my development, but I am not able to pass the data from the sheet. Please, any guidance would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69235067/3585796) on how you can get your activity from any composable function.